# GZip Error Reading from File in Python Script

Tags: python, gzip, compression

I have a .gz file that I'm trying to open and parse to be put into a database. Running the code below...

```
def process_file(filename):
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename, 'rU', 9) as uncompressed_file:
        uncompressed_file.next()  # Skip the headers

        for line in uncompressed_file:
            line = line.replace('\n', '').split('\t')
            # Do some more stuff with the line
```

Generates this error...

```
    File "path/to/script", line 169, in process_file
        uncompressed_file.next()  # Skip the headers
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 450, in readline
        c = self.read(readsize)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 256, in read
        self._read(readsize)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 307, in _read
        uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

What's particularly strange is that the code works perfectly on my local machine (Mac OSX 10.9.4), but not on my server (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS).

Any insight is appreciated as I'm currently out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure both archive files are same and one is not corrupted?

Comment: @konsolebox it appears the files are ok. I downloaded manually outside the program and unzipped them.

Comment: i have suddenly ecnoutered this issue. my scripts was previously working until suddenly i get these same errors from gzip.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue. It seems that using the 'with' syntax on gzip.open or gzip.GzipFile isn't fully supported on all platforms.

It's still not clear why it wasn't working consistently, but moving to this code resolved the issue:

```
def process_file(filename):
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    f.next() # Skip the headers

    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n', '').split('\t')

    f.close()
```